# JPL: is javax.persistence.Query.setParameter sql-injection safe?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, jpl

Can I sql-inject jpl parameter set by setParameter?
I mean, I know I can do it if I have something like this:

```
String nm = "'anything' or 'x'='x'--";
Query m = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Tbl p WHERE UPPER(p.name) = '" + nm + "'");
```

Can I do a similar thing with something like this?:

```
String nm = "'anything' or 'x'='x'--";
   Query m = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Tbl p WHERE UPPER(p.name) = :param").setParameter("param", nm.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is sql-injection safe. 
I looked in sql queries log: potentially dangerous symbols are escaped in the resulting sql